# JFrame opening empty

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to create a program and it's not showing anything in `JFrame` which is rather odd. The code seems to fit but java appears to be confused or something. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Img extends JFrame{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6362332275268668673L;
static JFrame panel = new JFrame();
private JButton next= new JButton("Next");

public Img(String a, String b){
    ShowPng1(a,b);
}

public void ShowPng1(String a, String b) {
    ImageIcon theImage = new ImageIcon("Icon_Entry_21.png");
    panel.setSize(300, 300);
    panel.setResizable(false);

    JLabel label = new JLabel(a);
    JLabel label2 = null;
    if(!b.isEmpty()){
        label2 = new JLabel("NOTE: " + b);
    }

    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(theImage);
    imageLabel.setOpaque(true);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    p1.add(imageLabel);
    p1.add(label);
    if(label2 != null)p1.add(label2);

    panel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setVisible(true);
}

public void ShowPng2(String a, String b) {
    ImageIcon theImage = new ImageIcon("Icon_Entry_21.png");
    panel.setSize(300, 300);
    panel.setResizable(false);

    JLabel label = new JLabel(a);
    JLabel label2 = null;
    if(!b.isEmpty()){
        label2 = new JLabel("NOTE: " + b);
    }

    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(theImage);
    imageLabel.setOpaque(true);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    p1.add(imageLabel);
    p1.add(label);
    if(label2 != null)p1.add(label2);
    p1.add(next);

    panel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setVisible(true);

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start mailrugames://play/0.3001");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error launching client.","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        ShowPng1("Applying patch NOW.","");
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start Start.bat");
        p1.waitFor();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done!","Note", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Img i = new Img("Preparing client for a patch","");
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start Clean.bat");
    p1.waitFor();
    Img.panel.dispose();

    i.ShowPng2("Launching client.","Make sure the client is fully patched before closing it and clicking `Next`");      
}
}
```

It should load an Image `imageLabel` into a container and show some text `label` and `label2` on the bottom. The difference between `ShowPng1()` and `ShowPng2()` is the Next button, it's located in `ShowPng2()`.

Comment: You are not adding components to the `JFrame` itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You are not adding components to the `JFrame` itself. You forget to add

```
public class Img extends JFrame{
  .
  .
  public void ShowPng1(String a, String b) {       
       //your code here, don't call panel.setVisible(true) here is not necesary
       this.add(panel);
  }

}
```

2) Don't call `panel.setVisible(true)` it's not necessary.. just call `i.setVisible(true)` in main.

3)To ensure that your code is running in the event dispatch thread wrap it with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)`

4)You should execute your command in a background thread if it's a long running task cause if not you will block your gui. Read more in [Concurrency in swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

5) Follow Java code conventions, method names starts with lower-case with a camel style.

6) Follow @HovercraftFullOfEels advices too.

Take a look to the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: I didn't get the `this.add(panel);` line. No matter where i put in my code it doesn't work, gives me an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: @nachokk `panel` is actually a static `JFrame` (see the 2nd class member, right below `serialVersionUID`). Which is wrong because `Img` class already extends from `JFrame` so it doesn't make any sense. Anyway +1 for good advices.

Comment: @nachokk ok, now I see and fixed my mistake. Now the only problem is positioning and label placement. I'm now a little concerned now that my image is part visible, showing only the mid part. Can I make some parts of my Grid bigger/smaller?

Comment: @VitalijKornijenko you should call `JFrame#pack()` before `setVisible()` to sizes components.

Answer (score 5):

1. You add nothing to the JFrame.
2. You never set the JFrame to visible.
3. You tie up the Swing event thread with a long-running process.

---

- You need to add components to the JFrame itself.
- You need to set it visible *after* components have been added.
- You need to run your long-running process in a background thread.
- You need to go through the Swing tutorials.
  Check out the [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) tag, click on the info link, and check out the resources that it contains.

Comment: @peeskillet: yep! That's why I separated it out as it's the most important. I can't believe that any window shows at all since no-where in his code does he call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame.